# Regex to extract a Variable from a Java Request

Tags: java, regex, notepad++, notepad

so I have a tool that scans a API for changes. If he found a change, he get a String like:

```
word=\don\u2019t\ item-id=\"1086\">\n        <span class=\
```

I want to extract the Number from `item-id` , however there are multiple Numbers in the response.

Is there a possible way to do so? (I also dont know if the Number will 4 digits or just 1-2)

so the Regex should search for something like "NUMBERS\" and print it. (for Java)

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Hey so I wrote a Tool to check an API as I said. 

At some point he convert the InStream to a String here:

                                `StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(instream, writer, "UTF-8");
    theString = writer.toString();`

The Variable: theString is HTML in Raw Format.

 other html Data   --- item-id=\"1086\">\n 

and as I said , I would love to extract `Item-ID` from the String and Print it.

Comment: [`item-id\D+\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/Ksip2d/1) ?

Comment: the best I was able to is: `/item-id=([^>]*)*/`  however, Java seems not working with that. 

so it extract:

`item-id=\"1086\"`

which I can regex again for only Numbers (I asume)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Interesting scenario, didn't think of that. Never had that the author deleted the answer of such a reason. But sounds reasonable, thanks.

Comment: @FrankMarlow: The String looks to be HTML text, and if so, your best bet is to use a dedicated HTML parser tool such as jsoup.

Comment: @Gurman - Is `\K` a Java RegEx Meta character? I know it is a feature for .Net, Perl, and PCRE RegEx.

Comment: @DevilsHnd No. But I thought since OP has tagged Notepad++, I should use it.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels ofc. No other Reason I am here, to steal all the Hard work. *Facepalm*

@DevilsHnd I through Regex for Java/Notepad are the same, is my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @FrankMarlow: my initial comment to Zabuza was regarding someone else's question, not this one. That question had been deleted, and so I could not comment on it, so sorry to hijack yours. I will delete that comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

It seems your way is the way to go, HOWEVER the HTML Code is delivered in Json. Here is an example:

{"success":1,"data":{"html":" HERE IS HTML CODE }

Any tip how to scrape it out and then get it done?

Comment: If response is like `{"success":1,"data":{"html":" HERE IS HTML CODE }` then you need JSON parser to traverse that JSON structure to `htm` key, get value from that key and then parse it with HTML parser. But that approach is based on assumption that JSON and HTML are properly formatted (``word=\don\u2019t\ item-id=\"1086\">\n        <span class=\`` looks like fragment of some longer HTML so parser may have problems with properly handling it).

Comment: FrankMarlow: there's your better answer -- @Pshemo's.

Comment: @FrankMarlow - Do you need to use RegEx for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487683/regex-to-extract-a-variable-from-a-java-request#comment81932043_47488313) it looks like you are receiving JSON structure

```
{
    ...
    "data":{
        "html":".. <a .. data-sku=\"XXX\"> ..",
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and you are interested in value of `data-sku` attribute.

In that case parse that JSON and traverse it to get HTML structure. You can use `org.json.JSONObject` for that (or other parser, pick one you like)

```
String response = "{\"success\":1,\"data\":{\"html\":\"<div class=\\\"inner\\\">\\n      <span class=\\\"title js-title-eligible\\\">Upgrade available<\\/span>\\n    <span class=\\\"title js-title-warning\\\"><strong>WARNING :<\\/strong> You don\\u2019t own a <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span><\\/span>\\n        <p class=\\\"explain js-title-eligible\\\">Buy this upgrade and it will be applicable to your <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span> from the My Hangar section.<\\/p>\\n    <p class=\\\"explain js-title-warning\\\">You can buy this upgrade but it will only be applicable on a <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span>.<\\/p>\\n\\n    <div class=\\\"price\\\"><strong class=\\\"final-price\\\">\\u20ac5<span class='super'>.41 <span class='currency'>EUR<\\/span><\\/span><\\/strong><div class=\\\"taxes js-taxes\\\">\\n  <div class=\\\"taxes-details trans-02s\\\">\\n    <div class=\\\"arrow\\\"><\\/div>\\n    Tax Included: <br \\/>\\n    <ul>\\n        <li>VAT 19%<\\/li>\\n        <\\/ul>\\n  <\\/div>\\n<\\/div><\\/div>\\n\\n\\n    <div>\\n      <a href=\\\"\\/pledge\\/Upgrades\\/Mustang-Alpha-To-Aurora-LN-Upgrade\\\" class=\\\"add-to-cart holosmallbtn trans-03s js-add-to-cart-ship ty-js-add-to-cart\\\" data-sku=\\\"1086\\\">\\n        <span class=\\\"holosmallbtn-top abs-overlay trans-02s\\\">BUY NOW<\\/span>\\n        <span class=\\\"holosmallbtn-bottom abs-overlay trans-02s\\\"><\\/span>\\n      <\\/a>\\n      <a href=\\\"\\/pledge\\/Upgrades\\/Mustang-Alpha-To-Aurora-LN-Upgrade\\\" class=\\\"more-details\\\">View more details<\\/a>\\n    <\\/div>\\n    \\n    <p class=\\\"explain info\\\">\\n      Upgrades that you buy can be found in your <a href=\\\"\\/account\\/pledges\\\">Hangar section<\\/a>.<br \\/>\\n      Click \\\"Apply Upgrade\\\" inside the Upgrade Pledge to pick where you want to apply it.\\n    <\\/p>\\n  <\\/div>\\n\\n\\n\\n\"},\"code\":\"OK\",\"msg\":\"OK\"}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
String html = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data") //pick data:{...} object
                        .getString("html");    //from that object get value of html:"..."
```

Now that you have `html` you can parse it with HTML parser (I am using jsoup)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String dataSku = doc.select("a[data-sku]") //get "a" element with "data-sku" attribute
                    .attr("data-sku");     //value of that attribute
```

Output: `1086`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Also Thanks to @Isuru Sameera

Comment: I would love to go a step futher but not sure if that is "easy" possible.

Comment: Well, it terms of code readability I would say that this is quite easy. Any other simplifications would require from us knowledge about all possible inputs. For instance we could consider using `substring` and `indexOf`, but that would become complex if there could be more `data-sku` strings. Not to mention handling changes of HTML format like `="..."` to `='...'`. Those problems ware already handled by parsers so I would stay with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String string = "{\"success\":1,\"data\":{\"html\":\"<div class=\\\"inner\\\">\\n      <span class=\\\"title js-title-eligible\\\">Upgrade available<\\/span>\\n    <span class=\\\"title js-title-warning\\\"><strong>WARNING :<\\/strong> You don\\u2019t own a <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span><\\/span>\\n        <p class=\\\"explain js-title-eligible\\\">Buy this upgrade and it will be applicable to your <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span> from the My Hangar section.<\\/p>\\n    <p class=\\\"explain js-title-warning\\\">You can buy this upgrade but it will only be applicable on a <span class=\\\"js-from-ship\\\"><\\/span>.<\\/p>\\n\\n    <div class=\\\"price\\\"><strong class=\\\"final-price\\\">\\u20ac5<span class='super'>.41 <span class='currency'>EUR<\\/span><\\/span><\\/strong><div class=\\\"taxes js-taxes\\\">\\n  <div class=\\\"taxes-details trans-02s\\\">\\n    <div class=\\\"arrow\\\"><\\/div>\\n    Tax Included: <br \\/>\\n    <ul>\\n        <li>VAT 19%<\\/li>\\n        <\\/ul>\\n  <\\/div>\\n<\\/div><\\/div>\\n\\n\\n    <div>\\n      <a href=\\\"\\/pledge\\/Upgrades\\/Mustang-Alpha-To-Aurora-LN-Upgrade\\\" class=\\\"add-to-cart holosmallbtn trans-03s js-add-to-cart-ship ty-js-add-to-cart\\\" data-sku=\"1086\\\">\\n        <span class=\\\"holosmallbtn-top abs-overlay trans-02s\\\">BUY NOW<\\/span>\\n        <span class=\\\"holosmallbtn-bottom abs-overlay trans-02s\\\"><\\/span>\\n      <\\/a>\\n      <a href=\\\"\\/pledge\\/Upgrades\\/Mustang-Alpha-To-Aurora-LN-Upgrade\\\" class=\\\"more-details\\\">View more details<\\/a>\\n    <\\/div>\\n    \\n    <p class=\\\"explain info\\\">\\n      Upgrades that you buy can be found in your <a href=\\\"\\/account\\/pledges\\\">Hangar section<\\/a>.<br \\/>\\n      Click \\\"Apply Upgrade\\\" inside the Upgrade Pledge to pick where you want to apply it.\\n    <\\/p>\\n  <\\/div>\\n\\n\\n\\n\"},\"code\":\"OK\",\"msg\":\"OK\"}";

    String pattern="(?<=data-sku=)([\\\\]*\")(\\d+)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);

     while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.println(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println("number="+matcher.group(2));
        }
```

Comment: For me it prints nothing, even with the String (string). Maybe I did a mistake?

Comment: result i got for this is  Start index: 31 End index: 35 
number=1086 .what is the string you use  .i mean string variable ?

Comment: Exact string (expires in a bit)

The actual Value is : "data-sku"  item-id was just an example, but it is easier if you work with the propper string I asume.

https://pastebin.com/jdULLKQP